# DEPRECATION WARNING: `named_routes.helpers` is deprecated, please use `route_defined?(route_name)` to see if a named route was defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run rspec, I get a deprecation warning when using Draper's `be_decorated` helper:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: `named_routes.helpers` is deprecated, please use `route_defined?(route_name)` to see if a named route was defined.
```

I'm using:

- rspec 3.0.0
- rspec-core 3.0.0
- rspec-expectations 3.0.0
- rspec-mocks 3.0.0
- rspec-rails 3.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, I just had an old version of rspec installed. Running `bundle update rspec rspec-rails` fixed my problem.